# Database changes versioning

Tags: database, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

my problem is that I can't find the way how to update sqlproj from command line to track database changes in repository. According to [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2014/07/15/msbuild-support-for-schema-compare-is-available/): "Projects not directly supported in this release", however have tried next command with no success:

```
msbuild PathToMyProject.sqlproj /t:SqlSchemaCompare /p:SqlScmpFilePath=SomePath/ComparationConfiguration.scmp /p:target=PathToMyProject.sqlproj /p:Deploy="true"
```

and can't find the way how to do this. Is it ever possible?
From the other side it looks like I can compare database schema to dacpac file(compilation output of sqlproj) to get changes that are not present on database project, however for automation of database changes tracking it looks useless because each time I got some changes I need manually open related solution, do comparison, update target database project and then checking changes to repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said by [@Steven Green](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39962828/2832586) at another answer there are no way currently to update database project using SSDT from command-line(hope it will be available soon), however have found another way to version database schema changes without database project(have left it for future in case any command-line method to update it would be added). Solution is based on C# program that generates database schema creation sql script using [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). So, we just store this script in repository and update on daily basis using CI server configuration that runs check and in case any changes found - commit them into repository. Leaving these steps for someone who faced the same problem:

1. It's needed reference next dependencies(mine were located at
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies):

   - Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
   - Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
   - Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
   - Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
2. Use next code to generate file:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Text;
   using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
   using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

   namespace ScriptGenerator {
       class Program {
           private static string GetTransferScript(Database database){
               var transfer = new Transfer(database) {
                                  CopyAllObjects = true,
                                  CopyAllSynonyms = true,
                                  CopyData = false,
                                  PreserveDbo = true,
                                  Options = {
                                                WithDependencies = true,
                                                DriAll = true,
                                                Triggers = true,
                                                Indexes = true,
                                                SchemaQualifyForeignKeysReferences = true,
                                                ExtendedProperties = true,
                                                IncludeDatabaseRoleMemberships = true,
                                                Permissions = true
                                            }

                              };
               var transferScript = new StringBuilder();
               foreach (var scriptLine in transfer.ScriptTransfer()) {
                   transferScript.AppendLine(scriptLine);
               }
               return transferScript.ToString();
           }

           static void Main(string[] args){
               var databaseName = "yourDataseName";
               var outputSqlFile = Path.GetFullPath($"DatabaseSchemaScript.sql");

               if (File.Exists(outputSqlFile))
                   File.Delete(outputSqlFile);

               using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseConnectionString"])) {
                   var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
                   if (!server.Databases.Contains(databaseName))
                       throw new Exception($"Database '{databaseName}' does not exists on server{connection.DataSource}");

                   var database = server.Databases[databaseName];
                   var transferScript = GetTransferScript(database);
                   using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputSqlFile)) {
                       sw.WriteLine(transferScript);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: That could also be accomplished with SqlPackage.exe option /Action:Script to a empty database from a .dacpac file which one can generate form the database.

What is still missing is a possibility to generate a .sqlproj from that script what you exported...

Comment: Actually the main aim of this post was to have some automated way of database changes versioning, .sqlproj was taken into account as it gave UI using which we was able to accomplish versioning, however it was really unexpected that same UI actions will be unavailable from the command line

Answer (score 2):

There is no command-line support for automating updates to a database project from a database. That's primarily because the workflow that SSDT is intended to enable is offline database development: the expectation is that changes are made to the database project first and are then published to the database.

Comment: Hello Steven, thank you for the answer. Not sure whether Visual Studio database project update functionality("Tools > SQL Server > New Schema Comparison...") is solely based on SSDT, but for me it looks a bit odd that using VS UI I can update it(sqlproj), but can't do this using command-line.

Comment: @Vova - I suspect that the UI feature is there in recognition that changes can sometimes be made "out of process" (often called "drift") and this provides a mechanism to copy the changes back into the dev source of truth, the database project in version control.